# How to set Nav as a default menu in wordpress

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, menus, navigation

I am new to WordPress and PHP.
I have created 4 menus but when I load the website (at path /), it shows "No post found"(because I am not setting any default page).
I wanted to use one of the nav as a default to loading at `/` instead of any default page.
How can I do that without using an extra plugin

Currently, I am using the Woocommerce plugin.

Comment: You want a menu to display instead of a page?  You will still need a page for that, even if it only calls `wp_nav_menu()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Comment: Okay...Is there any way by which i can redirect / to my nav slug for ex. Path / to /?xyz. By this my use case can be covered

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by a nav? When you refer to default page what are you referring to? Are these WooCommerce specific terms? It's not clear what your question is about

Comment: I am not using any pages/blogs on my website.. we have external affiliate products which shows under 4 different menus, based on the categories of the products. I wanted that visitors see product of the first menu whenever he visited for the first time.

Comment: I believe you need to rethink your project plan.  Using the code designed for site navigation to display products from a catalog is just a bad idea.  It is like using a screwdriver to paint your house.

Answer (score 0):

To assign menu please refer https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

There is Option to assign static front page  https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-static-front-page/

Comment: this will not fit in my scenario i do not want to use any static page as a  homepage. this will increase overhead to manage